# Vanity address generation for Segwit?

Tags: segregated-witness

Vanity address generation is currently strightforward for "old" Bitcoin addresses (starting with 1) with multiple software options available (oclvanitygen e.t.c).

Is there any options to generate SegWit Vanity address (starting with 3)? Or it is already possible to configure existing software for Segwit addresses?

Comment: I think you're confusing segwit with P2SH, addresses starting with 3 are P2SH addresses

Comment: SegWit addresses uses P2SH until BIP173 gets deployed.

Comment: also look at the discussion thread here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2934774.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There it is (for a while already):

- https://segwitaddress.org/ (vanity was removed here)
- https://github.com/coinables/segwitaddress (you can revert [the Jan 8th change](https://github.com/coinables/segwitaddress/commit/21cb0b4a94bfdf12d11ce11089ab37b700b3af30) from source)

even with an (inefficient) approach for vanity addresses.

- segvan does segwit and bech32: https://github.com/nym-zone/segvan (also see [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2934774.0))
- another C implementation for vanity segwit addresses is available e.g. on: https://github.com/kristapsk/segvan

And this lad is probably going to implement it later on: http://bitcoin-gen.org/ . you could of course support him doing so.

have fun

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? The proposed link just generates random addresses, not *vanity* addresses (addresses starting with a predefined character sequence)

Comment: that is  [because the dev removed it](https://github.com/coinables/segwitaddress/commit/21cb0b4a94bfdf12d11ce11089ab37b700b3af30) - but you are free to checkout an revert that change for the purpose or reimplement it. today also adding a c implementation to the list.

Answer (score 3):

Segwit, until BIP 173 is widely used, uses P2SH addresses. These addresses currently begin with a 3 and you can find them on the blockchain right now.

AFAIK, there is no software which will produce vanity P2SH addresses since there isn't just one thing that it can try over and over; the address is based on a script which could have anything, unlike the 1... Bitcoin addresses which are only based on one public key.

Since there are no P2SH vanity address generators, there is not one for Segwit. However it would not be hard to make such a software.

Comment: It's important to clarify that not all addresses that start with 3 are segwit.

Answer (score 3):

I just made one recently as a fun free time project - https://github.com/kristapsk/segvan

Comment: neat, just added your link above besides another c implementation, maybe you are interested if you didnt see it yet

Answer (score 2):

[VanitySearch](https://github.com/JeanLucPons/VanitySearch) supports standard P2PKH addresses and P2SH and BECH32 segwit addresses.

Performance on a GeForce 1050 Ti (compressed addresses):

- P2PKH: 226 MKey/s  (Add starting with 1)
- P2SH: 122 MKey/s   (Add starting with 3)
- BECH32: 226 MKey/s (Add starting with bc1q)